# Entity Framework Lazy Loading Unexpected Property Population on Extracted Data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

See following simplified example:

**Student Class:**

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public Grade Grade { get; set; }
}
```

**Grade Class:**

```
public class Grade
{
    public int GradeId { get; set; }
    public string GradeName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

**Context class:**

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public SchoolContext() : base()
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Grade> Grades { get; set; }
}
```

Program:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var ctx = new SchoolContext())
        {
            Grade[] grades = ctx.Grades.ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine(grades[0].Students == null);  // True - As expected
            var students = ctx.Students.ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine(grades[0].Students == null);  // False - ? Did not expect that
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
```

**The following happens:**

1. *Lazy loading* was enabled
2. List of `Grades` was saved into an array
3. As expected, `Students` *navigation property* of grade objects was `null`
4. Made a separate query to get `Students`
5. EF somehow filled up the `Students` *navigation property* of the array in memory.

This could end up in very *expensive* payloads to clients if not used with care.
Can anyone explain ***why*** and ***how*** did the navigation properties got populated in the array?

Comment: It seems lazy loading was not enabled, as it's set to `false` inside your `SchoolContext` constructor. `DbContext` keeps track of all the entities you query with the same DbContext instance, so I'd guess it populates related navigation properties under the hood due to that.

Comment: Just as a test, try changing your code to get grades with `ctx.Grades.AsNoTracking().ToArray();` and see if `grades[0].Students == null` is still false after loading students.

Comment: Another test you could do: try inserting `ctx.Grades.Detach(grades[0]);` before getting students from database, and check as well if `grades[0].Students == null` will be false after it.

Comment: Thanks @Alisson, my real example had `Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;` set. Modified here.

Comment: Also worth mentioning: if lazy load is enabled (which seems to be your case after your edit), it should load the navigation property `Student` as soon as it was accessed (as this is the purpose of lazy loading). However, it seems this is not happening when you first try it because your navigation property is not `virtual`. Maybe this was exactly what you wanted.

Comment: Querying with `AsNoTracking()` works. But it still looks dangerous to have to go back and set that in case the code is changes. Assumption would be as long as it is lazy loading, and I already extracted what I needed, my extracted objects should not be updated with extra load. Is this behavior detailed in documentation?

Comment: yep, you may find it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking) in the first paragraph. It's the docs for EF Core but the same applies to EF6.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the `grades[0].Students` is loaded after doing a query to get students from your database with `ctx.Students.ToArray();` is that you `DbContext` is **tracking changes**.

This is explained in [Entity Framework docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking):

> Tracking behavior controls whether or not Entity Framework Core will keep information about an entity instance in its change tracker. If an entity is tracked, any changes detected in the entity will be persisted to the database during SaveChanges(). Entity Framework Core **will also fix-up navigation properties** between entities that are obtained from a tracking query and entities that were previously loaded into the DbContext instance.

This is the EF Core docs, but this also applies to EF6 for .NET Framework.

If you want to disable this behavior, you may load your entities as no tracking:

```
ctx.Grades.AsNoTracking().ToArray();
```

...you could also disable it by default (e.g inside the `DbContext` constructor), the same way you do for lazy load.

---

Another way you could do that is to manually detach an object from the context. 
Then if you ever intended to make any changes and persist it to database, you should reattach your entity after querying students, and before making your changes:

```
using (var ctx = new SchoolContext())
{
    Grade[] grades = ctx.Grades.ToArray();
    Grade firstGrade = grades[0];
    Console.WriteLine(firstGrade.Students == null);  // True - as expected

    ctx.Grades.Detach(firstGrade); // stop tracking changes for this entity
    var students = ctx.Students.ToArray();
    Console.WriteLine(firstGrade.Students == null);  // True - still null

    // Let's reattach so we can track changes and save to database
    ctx.Grades.Attach(firstGrade);
    firstGrade.GradeName = "Some new value"; // will be persisted, as this is being tracked again
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Also, it's worth mentioning with **lazy load enabled**, accessing `grades[0].Students` the first time should make EF load that navigation property if it was not loaded yet (which is precisely its purpose), however it seems this is not happening because your navigation property **is not `virtual`**.